# How can an brand/company be credited in a paper?

Tags: citations, authorship

Say, a brand/company like Intel provides a free service — specifically large computational resources (a cluster that could be used for AI, machine learning etc.). In business, it falls under "sponsorship". In return for its sponsorship the brand wants... VISIBILITY. And of course, "visibility" can come in many forms.

But the essence is:
It's a business transaction. Not a charity event.

For a business/brand being associated with scientific research (which results in a paper) has value. For the researcher writing a paper getting free resources has value.

A business sponsors research and expects **brand visibility** in return.

So, the question is:

How can the brand get *maximum* visibility for sponsoring a paper?
(or sponsoring the **research** that results in a paper)

Getting merely a footnote mention or being hidden somewhere in the back in an "acknowledgments section" seems like a poor value to the brand/company providing the resources.

Of course, in general, one could argue that there are better ways to do "marketing". But here we assume that the company WANTS to provide resources and hopes to get some brand visibility out of that. (the more the better)

Comment: Many HPC centers (or e.g. research facilities providing instrument time, or places that host many visiting researchers for that matter) have instructions for how they prefer/request to be credited (e.g. by specifying a phrasing that typically would go in the acknowledgments).

Comment: The confusion here is probably due to your original question not making any mention of private companies, so I (and probably some others) figured you were talking about more conventional (for us) university HPC resources.

Comment: Unless there's a very special resource involved (e.g. prototype quantum computers) or a particularly high-profile project, I suspect providing compute time is not a particularly effective marketing exercise for a company. That said, companies like Intel, AMD, Nvidia etc. are often quite involved with the construction of new high-end compute clusters that, as it happens, can provide them longterm visibility and prestige, at least in some circles.

Comment: Indeed, echoing Anyon, "institution" usually implies an academic or at least government entity (or possibly religious or social non-profit type organization). Companies are not usually called "institutions". You also asked "how can an institution be credited" and got a simple answer. It seems maybe your actual question was "how can a company get more credit than usual" which is a completely different question. I don't know why you'd expect people to answer a different question than you asked.

Comment: @BryanKrause Thanks. That's a fair point. My fault.

Comment: I cannot sort out what problem is being solved here.  Is this question from the point of view of the company?

Comment: @TerryLoring I have modified the question body and the headline. Yes, this question is from the point of view of the company. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acknowledgement in the paper is the credit on the academic side. That's all the credit a company gets or deserves within academia, it's perfectly suitable to be in the acknowledgements. Others who provided their time or money will also be found there. Often the methods section will also describe the computing resources. Other academics who want to use the same resources will know where to go.

Marketing is the company's business and is up to their goals.

They can make a TV ad saying "our resources were provided free to 1,000 academic projects with a total worth of $XYZ, so buy our brand of paper towels".

They can say to their computing customers "hey computing customers, here are some papers where people used our stuff with good results, therefore you can expect good results, too, when you pay to use the same resources."

And, importantly, they can go to the government agency that sponsored their company to develop this computing resource (don't think that every time a company does this sort of thing they are actually spending their own money... Companies get government grants, too) they can include it in the successful use of those funds towards a cause for the public good.

Answer (score 9):

The normal way to do this, is through the Acknowledgements section. This could contain a line like:

> "HPC resources for this work were provided by institution X."

Comment: Where is the acknowledgments section usually located? i.e. how easy is it for people to notice that credit? Are there ways for the institution to get credit that are not "normal"?

Comment: Acknowledgment sections are usually either at the end of the introduction or at the end of the paper. Another location (not really a section) is a footnote on the first page.

Comment: @WebDevBooster This seems like an XY problem. Why do you want to know if there are other ways?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Are you asking why an institution would want to maximize return on investment? Is that what you want to know?

Comment: @WebDevBooster "Maximize return on investment"? What does that even mean in this context?

Comment: @WebDevBooster I am not. Publishing a paper does not get any "returns" that are relevant for a HCP cluster.

Comment: Providing resources has a cost associated with it, hasn't it? And if an industrial institution provides resources for free, it's not unreasonable the institution would want something in return, is it? That "something" would be the return in this context. Those "returns" are very much relevant. Otherwise, the institution wouldn't consider providing free resources in the first place.

Comment: Or does an institution like Intel provide resources solely for the goodness of their heart? Or just for fun?

Comment: @WebDevBooster Why does that something have to be something in a paper?

Comment: @TimRias A brand like Intel provides a free service (which in business is called sponsorship). In return for its sponsorship the brand wants... what exactly? VISIBILITY! That's right. So, the question is: How can the brand get *maximum* visibility for sponsoring a paper? If a researcher sends a big thank-you note on a postcard, that probably won't do. So, how else are you going to give visibility to the sponsor brand if it's not "something in the paper"? How will the paper readers know that the brand has provided resources if it isn't mentioned in the paper?

Comment: @WebDevBooster There are other ways of getting visibility related to the sponsored research, other than visibility in a paper. (e.g. in related presentations, mentions in related press releases, on the group/researcher/institute website.)

Comment: @TimRias Aha, that's what you meant. Yes, those things would be definitely valuable too. I guess, they could be more valuable. So, thanks for the input. Still, a paper is a piece of *published* research. So, a lot of value here comes from prestige.

Answer (score 1):

Usually an institution will partecipate in studies if they have an interest in it.
For example, this researcher:

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Pradeep-Dubey-4

has a long career workign for Intel, and there are many scientific papers which base their results on computations perfomed on Big Blue (Intel supercomputer) with their name and Intel as their institution/affiliation as co-author, papers spanning from statistics to geophysics.

Surely he contributed more than providing the script grammar to launch simulations on Big Blue, but having a person from the hosting institution actively involved in the computations does not seem a far fetch to me.

Comment: So, to get a more prominent credit (rather than being buried in an acknowledgments section or in a footnote somewhere) an organization like Intel provides someone who is credited as a co-author and has an employment association with that organization. Would that be a correct way to put it?

Comment: @WebDevBooster In that case the organization is not merely providing computational resources as a service, they are directly involved in the study if their employee has an authorship role (which is certainly plausible for providing support for a key resource in a project).

Comment: Right. So, if Intel wants greater "visibility" for their sponsorship (because that's what it is in the world of business — a sponsorship which is expected to have a return on investment which in this case means brand visibility/exposure), then they find ways to make such a branded co-authorship "plausible". Or perhaps, they even make such a "plausible" co-authorship a condition for providing their services.

Comment: @WebDevBooster I am not sure it is the most cost-effective way to increase visbility, I think a big company wanting to promote its cloud/computational service would be better doing cost-dumping trying to shut-down the competitors. Or buying them (let's remember that PowerPoint already existed as a software ... which had already all the functionalities, Microsoft bought it in the early 90s).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, what you want to do is inappropriate. A research paper is not a suitable venue for advertising or providing brand visibility to a corporation. Any attempt, beyond an acknowledgment or the listing of an affiliation, is likely to be shut down by the editors. Please don't try.

However, there are other ways in which a researcher could draw attention to their sponsor. Perhaps the best is to create a **good personal website**.

It is common for academics to create websites where they might do any of the following: post preprints of their papers; advertise their work and that of their students and postdocs; recruit prospective students; provide links to resources they value; and generally draw attention to where they feel it is deserved. If I'm interested in a researcher's work, I will often find may way to their website at some point.

So, create a good website promoting the research, and add as much brand visibility for the corporate sponsor as you like.